# Kega Fusion not quitting on "Escape" when launched with -fullscreen

Tags: emulation, hardware, sega-genesis, kega-fusion

I'm building an arcade cabinet and using Kega Fusion, but I need an easy way to exit the emulator. There is no way to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> for quitting the emulator, due to hardware limitations (I'm using I-Pac for key input so solutions involving rebinding keys don't work for me).

I found several mentions online that Kega should quit on <kbd>Esc</kbd> when launched with the `-fullscreen` command line option, but at least for me it is still toggling between fullscreen and windowed mode like <kbd>Esc</kbd> normally does.

Anyone got an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this is that I-Pac should allow you to utilize alt+F4, my understanding is that most people don't use ctrl, alt and shift keys as much as possible so that there are no conflicts with the OS but with iPac you can as stated on the [website](http://www.ultimarc.com/ipac1.html)

> Shift functions. Holding "Start1" and pressing other buttons sends a
>   range of codes for MAME functions such as "escape", "Coin 1", "tab",
>   "enter". This means no extra buttons are needed on the cabinet. In
>   programmable mode any input can be the shift key and all keys can be
>   programmed with a shifted code.

What this implies is that you can assign an alternate key function so that you won't get a conflict unless you are holding start1 - this way you could program in that (Start1+"otherkey") = alt+F4 without the problem of conflict.

I really hope this helps - I haven't built one myself but i have been part of building one with my friends and i believe this is how we managed it as we ran into the same issue.

Might take some playing with and depending on the emulator you might be able to change the key config with that. or get some macro software that says when esc is pressed procede with alt-f4